# Android Custom RadioButton Override onDraw called constantly

Tags: android, radio-button

I have created a custom RadioButton Class, and override its onDraw function as below:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        Log.d( "Custom radio button" ,  "this run onDraw() "  + (times++) +  " times! ");  
    }
```

In fact, there is many code inside the onDraw function, but i have already commented all of them, but the onDraw function still gets call again and again...

I tried to add the custom radio button to a radio group as below:

```
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.main.radioGroup);
    customRadioButton = new customRadioButton(this);
    radioGroup.addView(customRadioButton);
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The `OnDraw()` function is designed to be called many times over the course of the application (anytime the `View` is invalidated, and in other situations as well). It might be that its being called more than once for a reason. Is it being called over and over (like an infinite loop) or are you concerned just because its being called more than once?

Comment: It should be an infinite loop, because it didn't stop even i didn't give any input to the app for a few mins.

I am trying to test what make it recall the OnDraw() function again and again. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your whole OnDraw() statement. Because you might be causing OnDraw() to be called inside the function (directly or indirectly) which would cause a loop.